# Azure Resource Manager VM can't connect from Internet

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network

I created a azure vm through resource manager and deployed an application on it. the application works fine when you try to access it from the vm. but when i try it from outside(through internet) it doesn't work. i created an inbound security rule in NSG and opened the port through vm firewall inbound rules too. please give some tips as to why this isn't working

Answer (score 1):

you may consider using * versus 80 or 443 for the source port range hopefully this will resolve your connection issue.

Comment: Could you help explain why this would address the OP's issue, to make for a better answer?

Comment: If you remove the NSG completely, are you able to access the application remotely? If so, then it is probably an NSG issue; otherwise, it's probably an application/networking issue of some sort; possible explanations include: the application is bound to localhost/127.0.0.1 instead of, say, 0.0.0.0 or some other network interface; the application itself has permissions that are blocking you from using it remotely; etc.